# compare preceding text and get the output

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I've the below XML.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<body>
  <para>
      <phrase>[1.001]</phrase> Arrest is for the pu</para>
    <para>
      <phrase>[1.002]</phrase> Brandon J said in 
    </para>
    <para>
      <phrase>[1.001]</phrase> Singapore used to be and is still
    </para>
</body>
```

and the below XSL.

```
        <xsl:template name="para" match="para">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="./node()[1][self::page]" mode="first"/>
        <div>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="./@align">
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para align-</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="./@align"/></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:text>para</xsl:text></xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="phrase">
       <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(preceding::phrase,.)">
                <xsl:text>Duplicate </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select ="."/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:text>Non Duplicate </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select ="."/>             
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>

    </xsl:template>
```

Here I'm trying to match the `phrase` with any of the preceding `phrase`, If it is matched i want to print `Duplicate //phrase value` otherwise `non duplicate \\phrase value`. But here when i try to run these, it is throwing me the below error for third case.

```
 XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of
  contains() ("[1.001]", "[1.002]")
```

Here since there is `[1.001]` in preceding phrase, i want it to print `Duplicate [1.001]`.

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to fix it.

Here is a [working DEmo](http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtk/1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Either check `contains(preceding::phrase[1],.)` if you want to check the immediately preceding `phrase` or `preceding::phrase[contains(., current())]` if you want to check that there is any preceding `phrase` containing the current value.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, but it should be `preceding::phrase[contains(., current())]`

Comment: Here is the exact problem that i'm facing, please help me fix it. http://xsltransform.net/3NzcBtk/2. Thanks